# Wc and reading from a file

Tags: bash, wc

I want to check the number of lines of a certain file without using a temporary file using wc.
I tried using something like this: `var=${wc -l a.txt}` or `wc -l a.txt | read line` but both didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to store the output of a command is `var=$(command)` instead of the `var=${command}` you used.

Hence, this will do:

```
var=$(wc -l a.txt)    # returns XX a.txt
```

To store just the number, do

```
var=$(wc -l < a.txt)  # returns XX
            ^
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I do echo var it prints 3 a.txt and I dont need the name of the file. When I tried to do var[0], it still printed the whole 3 a.txt, Thanks again!

Comment: +1 If one wants the plain line count only then `var=$(cat a.txt | wc -l)` would give the desired result.

Comment: Note this will store both the file name and the line count in `var`. Use `var=$(wc -l < a.txt)` to store just the line count, or something like `printf -v var "%d" $(wc -l < a.txt)` to discard the leading spaces from the output of `wc`.

Comment: This is more apt `var=$(wc -l < a.txt)`

Comment: @Sefi does it work to you if you do `var=$(wc -l < a.txt)` instead of `var=$(wc -l a.txt)`? It does to me, but want to make sure if it does to you before updating. OK now I see -- thanks guys, we think alike (but I am slower :D)

Comment: @Sefi `var` is not an array, so `${var[0]}` will not do anything special.

Answer (score 1):

Beware!

`wc -l < a.txt` might look like the correct answer... but if you want to use that number somewhere else, like in a calculation or in a test within an if-block, your script might fail.  Why?  Because `wc -l` gives you the number but it can be preceded by some white space, depending on your `wc` release (please, take a look at the comments).  In order to get the number, and *only* the number, you could try:

```
echo $(wc -l < a.txt)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Have you checked that "wc -l gives you the number but the output is a text, preceded by a/some space(s)"? First of all, bash does not understand text/integer values, for it all are strings that you can work with. And there is no space at all, although if there was any it would also show when `echo`ing it as you suggest.

Comment: @fedorqui - It's true regarding the text/integer types, but that doesn't mean the developer trying to make his/her code to work may have not noted he/she might be using a number as a text or viceversa.  Regarding the leading white space, please take a look at this thread: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2005-01/msg00029.html - Seems to be an issue with some `wc` releases.  As one of them suggested: _POSIX allows leading spaces, though, so you can't rely on this behavior in portable code... So regardless of coreutils behavior portable scripts should code for wc emitting spaces_

Comment: Well you are referring an issue of `wc` in 2005, I guess new version are ok with it. With my `wc (GNU coreutils) 8.20` is completely fine, for example.

Comment: @fedorqui - Sure, but some people may be using legacy systems out there...  And, if you want your code to be portable, then you should be aware of this.  AIX's ksh shows white space too; a few weeks ago I tried porting one bash script to ksh and failed because of this.  So, I'm just trying to help :)